# WAPM and CRS across all production plans

Tags: microeconomics

In Hal Varian's Book "Microeconomic analysis" on page 35 he gives the following description of a profit maximising firm.

> ...If the firm is maximising profits, then the
>   observed net output choice at price pt must have a level of profit at least as
>   great as the profit at any other net output the firm could have chosen. We
>   don't know all the other choices that are feasible in this situation, but we
>   do know some of them-namely, the other choices $y^s$ for $s = 1,. . . , T$ that
>   we have observed. Hence, a necessary condition for profit maximisation is
>   that
>   $$p^ty^t\ge p^ty^s$$
>   for all $t$ and $s=1,...,T$
>
> We will refer to this condition as the **Weak Axiom of Profit Maximisation
>   (WAPM)**.

In the case of a firm which has a production function with one input and one output where $p=w$, such that $p$ is the price the output is sold and $w$ is the price of the input across all [production possibilities sets](http://www.oxfordreference.com/view/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803100348928). Can such a firm be called profit maximising at any level of output?

Comment: You did not define $p$, $w$ and "production plan", so this is quite difficult to answer.

Comment: @denesp better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can, because the maximal profit is 0, and that level is attained at all output levels.

A similar problem is a profit maximizing firm with constant returns to scale. If such a firm has a maximal profit it can attain then that profit level is 0. If the maximal profit level was something else, it could be increased by doubling or halving production.